# Taking a div element with JQuery and a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

We are working in a Rails application with Prototype and jQuery (we want to remove Protoype at all, but is a migration and we have to do it progressively), and we have a form that can add many fields with jQuery. This fields have a very weird ID:

`viaje_contratos_attributes_0_cargas_attributes_1385986834726_punto_attributes_municipio`

In this field, we need to work with autocomplete jquery, and our problem is take this ID. We've tried the following code:

`$('input[id$="_punto_attributes_municipio"]').autocomplete({

   source: $('input[id$="_punto_attributes_municipio"]').data('autocomplete-source')

});`

What's the problem? What we have to modify?

Thanks in advance!!

#### Updated [12/02/2013 - 15:35]:

Thanks Jacob Bundgaard for your replies, but still not working :(. But you have made me to think and maybe, because this form is created after load the view with `append` function, your answer maybe not work for that? Could be?

Anyway, I hardcoded the ui class `ui-autocomplete-input` and `autocomplete="off"` but still not working :S.

A temporal solution, obviously, have been coding inline, after the div appended, the jQuery script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a class instead of using id's for something for which they were not intended? That'll make your jQuery significantly simpler, and will probably only take a minor change in your Rails-code.

Comment: Well... the class is not much better...  `class="viaje_contratos_attributes_0_cargas_attributes_1385986834726_punto_attributes_municipio"`

Comment: I don't understand Spanish (and I don't think code should be localised, but that's another issue), but something like this: $(".autocompleteMunicipio").autocomplete({ source: $(this).data("autocomplete-source") });

Comment: Of course you should not give each input element a separate class, but use that same class for all inputs which require the same functionality.

Comment: I'm agree with you... code should not be localised!! But change this project is very complex... so we have to work with it :S. I'll try to put a class and I tell you if it works. Thanks!

Comment: We have try adding a class but nothing happens... `$('.test-class').autocomplete({source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')});`and in the view we have `<%= text_field_tag "#{prefijo}[nombre_municipio]", nil, :id =>"#{prefijo}_municipio", :class=>"test-class", data: {autocomplete_source: search_municipio_by_nombre_path}%>` what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't look at how the jQuery autocomplete plug-in worked. You'll have to iterate over the elements and call the plug-in on each one with the relevant data. Try something like this:
$(".test-class").each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).data("autocomplete-source") });
});

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but still not working... I've updated the post.

Comment: You will have to run the autocomplete plug-in on new elements after you insert them using append.